# Adding a custom attribute for a better separation between JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Using jQuery and backbone.js, I would like to separate the JavaScript from the HTML as much as possible.
Is it possible to add a `custom attribute` for a better separation between JavaScript and HTML?
And then how can I use the new jQuery selector?

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="todo-input" class="todo-input" tid="tid-attribute" > hello world </input>

// The DOM events
// I would like to use another selector tid and not class or id
events: {
  "keypress #todo-input" : "updateOnEnter" // I would like to use another selector tid not id,
  "keypress .todo-input" : "updateOnEnter" // I would like to use another selector tid and not class
}
```

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want separation ? or the attributes bother you. As far as i can tell this is work of the view, do not render anything from the server for the backbone app to depend on. This will make your backbone app deploy anywhere.

Comment: HTML `class` attributes are used for all sorts of things, not just for styling with CSS. There's nothing wrong with adding extra classes to an element just for use in selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 allows for custom data attributes that start with `data-`:

```
<input type="text" data-custom-attr="somevalue">
```

Then in your backbone events declaration:

```
"keypress [data-custom-attr='somevalue']" : "updateOnEnter"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$('input[type="text"]').attr('tid', 'tid-attribute');
```

OR

```
$('input[type="text"]').attr('data-tid', 'tid-attribute');
```